# df hide ifree etc (GNU)

Tags: df, coreutils

(analogous to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263437/df-hide-ifree-iused-512-blocks-customize-column-format-dont-show-inode-info for BSD)

How can I hide the columns beginning with `i` (`iused`, `ifree`) and/or `512-blocks`? I just want to know how close to full my disks are, I don't want their life story.

```
$ /bin/df

Filesystem                                512-blocks       Used Available Capacity  iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2                               975093952  719904648 254677304    74% 90052079 31834663   74%   /
devfs                                            368        368         0   100%      637        0  100%   /dev
map -hosts                                         0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home                                      0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /home
/dev/disk3s1                               242555008  206423680  36131328    86%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/SERIALS
map -static                                        0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/ubuntu
map -static                                        0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/Large_backup
map -static                                        0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/Large
map -static                                        0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/Unsorted
map -static                                        0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/Record
map -static                                        0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/Documentaries
192.168.1.2:/                              115345392   86998112  22441976    80%   421924  3249100   11%   /Volumes/ubuntu
192.168.1.2:/media/myusername/Documentaries  488397160  446990432  41406728    92%    15979 20720153    0%   /Volumes/Documentaries
192.168.1.2:/media/myusername/Record         625121216  625121216         0   100%   125517    38323   77%   /Volumes/Record
192.168.1.2:/media/myusername/Unsorted       625137280  604966376  20170904    97%   346496 10099404    3%   /Volumes/Unsorted
192.168.1.2:/media/myusername/Large         1953520000 1949403312   4116688   100%  1379836  2218604   38%   /Volumes/Large
192.168.1.2:/media/myusername/Large_backup   115345392   86998112  22441976    80%   421924  3249100   11%   /Volumes/Large_backup
```

## Version info

Undesired beheavior (excess info) found on each of the following systems:

- `GNU coreutils 8.28  September 2017  DF(1)` - `Darwin Kernel Version 17.2.0`
- `BSD . May 8, 1995  BSD` - `Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0:`

Desired behavior (not displayed by default) IS observed on:

- `GNU coreutils 8.25  February 2016  DF(1)` - on `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`, `4.4.0-104-generic #127-Ubuntu`

Comment: [df man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/df) you're already using parameters to show that information so leave them out. Check whenever you have an alias set up for those commands.

Comment: There is no alias, I am running `/bin/df`

Comment: environment variables might affect the behaviour too.

Comment: `env | grep POSIXLY_CORRECT` returns nothing for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: Looking at the source code on github, it seems df usually doesn't show both blocks and inodes. My guess is that your build is personalized, it's weird. I tried fiddling with options locally to show both and couldn't. It's possible that you don't have the option of not showing both... unless you compile df yourself. :-/

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to do pipes, you can try this:

```
df | rev | awk '{$2=$3=$4=$8=""}' | rev
```

That is, if you have rev and awk.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion even if I'd rather not accept that as the answer. It seems like this is a bug, so a temporary key binding (or alias, though I don't like aliases) of this could be my solution for now.